# learning rate in Adaboost sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, adaboost

I can't figure out what does learning_rate stand for in sklearn implementation of Adaboost. When i see the original algorithm i don't see any "learning_rate"...

Meanwhile i can see from https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost that the training errors are weighted thanks to $D_t(i)$ (where $i$ is attached to the $i$th training instance in the training matrix $X$). Is there any relation between the sklearn "learning_rate" and this $D_t$ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrinkage parameter in Adaboost?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82323/shrinkage-parameter-in-adaboost)

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82323/shrinkage-parameter-in-adaboost/355632#355632

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte It is worth noting, that although the learning parameter is a natural extension, it is not mentioned in the papers referenced by [scikitlearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html), which do represent classic version and SAMME. In [Experiments with a New Boosting Algorithm by Freund and Shapire](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/teaching/COLT/boostingexperiments.pdf) M1 and M2 are presented (again), both without learning rate. I wonder what the official reference for the learning rate / shrinkage parameter is.

Comment: Fair point - I don't know where it comes from - It doesn't seem to be here either https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/samme.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The official [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html) states that `"The learning rate shrinks the contribution of each regressor by learning_rate."`. Thus, basically we need to understand three concepts:

***1. Weak Classifier***

A model whose error rate is only slightly better than random guessing, that is to say, 50% accuracy.

***2. Boosting***

This technique has the objective to apply $K$ different times (sequentially) a model to modified versions of the data. So, suppose at each iteration $i \in \{1,2,..., K\}$ you build a new tree model $T_{i}$

\begin{align}
     T_{i+1}(x) = T_{i}(x) + \alpha M(x),
\end{align}

where $$M(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{J} t(x, \theta_{j})$$
is the sum of trees with different paramaters $\theta_{j}$ and $\alpha$ is the learning rate between 0 and 1.

***3. Learning Rate***

This parameter controls **how much I'm going to contribute with the new model to the existing one**. Normally there is trade off between the number of iterations $K$ and the value of $\alpha$. In other words, **when taking smaller values of alpha ($\alpha \approx 0$) you should consider more $K$ iterations, so that your base model (the weak classifier) continues to improve**. According to Jerome Friedman, it is suggested to set $\alpha$ to smaller values ($\alpha < .1$).

Comment: you saved my search. Thank you.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for this? Your explanation makes sense and is very clear, but I'm concerned about the discrepancy with [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) that say LR is between 0 and inf, not 0 and 1, and that higher LR increases contribution of each classifier - opposite of what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this is mainly the problem with sklearn docs. Observe in a [2021 GitHub issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19521) about this exact question, not one person has referenced a paper that is actually implemented, and entire discussion is purely about style.

I think @XavierBourretSicotte's answer above should be the accepted one, because it is consistent with [sklearn's implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/306608e622bb3fb55095a97405b9ef0f1ad901d9/sklearn/ensemble/_weight_boosting.py#L669). I'll also reopen that issue and suggest a link to the paper and/or precise definition of the LR.